# ForEach loop with dynamic variable

Tags: button, dynamic, swiftui

I need to show two different images depending on an @State bool, so that when the user presses the image it shows the second image and when the user releases it goes back to showing the first image. This all works perfectly, however I have a situation where I need to do the same thing in a ForEach loop and since I don't believe Swift can handle dynamic variables, I can't see how to make this happen.

In the code below you'll see the struct of how the button is configured, and then it's called in the ForEach loop of the MainView. The btnHover variable needs to change for each iteration or else all the buttons show the hover image when a single one is pressed.

Also, I cannot place this into a separate struct and then call to it in the main view. I spent quite a bit of time going down that road today and it seems that if you call a NavigationLink from a separate struct, you can no longer pop to root. I don't understand it, but that's apparently the deal. So, I need to make this work in the main view, not in a separate struct.

The real code is quite a bit more complex (i.e. each button is actually a NavigationLink), but I tried to put together as simplistic of an example as I could.

```
struct PressActions: ViewModifier {
    var onPress: () -> Void
    var onRelease: () -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .simultaneousGesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged({ _ in
                        onPress()
                    })
                    .onEnded({ _ in
                        onRelease()
                    })
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func pressAction(onPress: @escaping (() -> Void), onRelease: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> some View {
        modifier(PressActions(onPress: {
            onPress()
        }, onRelease: {
            onRelease()
        }))
    }
}

struct DynamicBtn: View {
    var btnName: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Image(btnName == true ? "DynamicHover" : "Dynamic")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var btnHover: Bool = false
    let user = [Tim, John, Joe, Mary]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(user, id: \.self) { user in
            VStack {
                DynamicBtn(btnName: btnHover)
                .pressAction {
                    btnHover = true
                } onRelease: {
                    btnHover = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could not compile your code. There is no `.pressAction` or `onRelease:` for `Views`, such as your  `DynamicBtn`.

Comment: The NavigationLink thing sounds suspicious to me, but if you really can't separate out the subview, you could store a dictionary that stores the hover state by ID of the model. Unfortunately, since you haven't included any model code (what type is `Tim`, `John`, etc? Why are they keyed by `.self` and not `id`?) it's not possible to provide an answer with code for you.

Comment: The behaviour you get with your current code (assumed since it does not compile for me), 
is because you only have one `@State private var btnHover: Bool = false`.
You need one for **each** user, not one for all. Re-structure your code to cater for this.

Comment: You can't restructure to have additional bools in a foreach loop because they will all use the same bool. That's the whole problem. I'm simply asking how to change the name of the bool variable for each iteration.

Comment: I updated the post with the press action so it will compile now. Also, I totally agree about the not being able to separate it out into a subview. I can do that and the navlinks work, but I cannot pop to root for some reason if I do so. It completely breaks the pop to root functionality.

Comment: No, it won't compile. You haven't included `Tim`, `John`, `Joe`, etc and it's not clear what type they are or why they aren't identifiable.

Comment: Change it however you need. The actual foreach is over Core Data so I can't include that in my example. But it shouldn't matter anyway, because the question is about changing the btnHover variable in a foreach loop. Doesn't really matter what you are iterating over.

Comment: Take a look at ButtonStyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this approach, to be able to "press" on your
`DynamicBtn` and show a particular image, and then release the "press" to display the original image:

```
struct MainView: View {
    let users = [User(name: "Tim"), User(name: "John"), User(name: "Joe"), User(name: "Mary")]
    @State var selectedUser: User?  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
            DynamicBtn(btnName: selectedUser == user) // <-- here
                .pressAction {
                    selectedUser = user  // <-- here
                } onRelease: {
                    selectedUser = nil   // <-- here
                }
        }
    }
}

// for testing
struct User: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name = ""
}
```

Note: you can just use `Image(btnName ? "DynamicHover" : "Dynamic")` in `DynamicBtn`.

Comment: That was brilliant and the perfect answer to my question. Thanks!